# modal is not showing up at once

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a table and each row has a delete button. Once that delete button is pressed, a modal should show up to ask for some confirmation.

The problem here is that, the *very first time* i load the page, I have to click twice (in the delete button i want) to see the modal. Once i did that, the next time i press on any delete button of any row the modal shows up at once...just one click is needed.

I would like to know why and how i can correct it.

**View:**

```
<!-- modal -->
  <div id="myModal3" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel3" aria-hidden="true">
     <div class="modal-header">
       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"></button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel3">Eliminar</h3>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-body">
        <p></p>
     </div>
     <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Cerrar</button>
        <button data-dismiss="modal" class="btn red" id="btnYes">Confirmar</button>
     </div>
   </div>
   <!-- end modal -->
```

**js file:**

```
function callToModal(data){
 $('#myModal3 .modal-body p').html("Desea eliminar al usuario " + '<b>' + data + '</b>' + ' ?');

  $('.confirm-delete').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  $('#myModal3').data('id', id).modal('show');
  });

  $('#btnYes').click(function() {
  // handle deletion here
  var id = $('#myModal3').data('id');
  // alert(id);
  $.ajax({
    url: "deleteFrontUser",
    type: 'POST',
    data: 'id='+id,
      success: function(html){
        // alert(html);
        $('[data-id='+id+']').parents('tr').remove();
        $('#myModal3').modal('hide');
      }      
    });
   return false;
  });
};
```

Comment: What jquery modal plugin are you using?

Comment: @Bobby5193 no idea, how can i check? i was looking at the template but didn't find a version

Comment: See if you can reproduce the problem by creating a `bootply`, Here is an example http://www.bootply.com/97125 It looks like your modal should show up right away the first time it's opened.  There may be something wrong with the way `id` is getting initialized the first time and it throwing an error that wont open the modal.  If you can demonstrate the problem in a `bootply` I can probably help.

Comment: @Trevor hi, i was already writing code in bootply, how amazing tool. Here you go: http://bootply.com/97366

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem was that i was calling a function (one click) and then nothing triggered. I change the code and now it's working super! here you can check it out:

http://bootply.com/97366

View:

Is the same that in my question, but only changed the modal name to "myModal".

Js File:

```
$('#myModal').on('show', function() {
 var id = $(this).data('id'),
 username = $(this).data('usern');

 $('#myModal .modal-body p').html("Desea eliminar al usuario " + '<b>' + username + '</b>' + ' ?');
})

$('.confirm-delete').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var user = $(this).data('title');

  $('#myModal').data('id', id).modal('show');
  $('#myModal').data('usern', user).modal('show');
});

$('#btnYes').click(function() {
var id = $('#myModal').data('id');

$.ajax({
  url: 'deleteFrontUser',
  type: 'POST',
  data: 'id='+id,
  success: function(html){

    $('[data-id='+id+']').parents('tr').remove();
    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
  }      
});
return false;
});
```

What i also did, was to add "data-title" atribute in the html, like this:

```
<td><a href="#" class="confirm-delete btn mini red-stripe" role="button" data-title="{$frontuser->username}" data-id="{$frontuser->id}">Eliminar {$frontuser->id} {$frontuser->username} </a></td>
```

data-title stores the username so jquery can sustract it later. Please notice that i'm using smarty template engine.

Hope this can help newbies like me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try saving the id you pass there (I suppose it's the id of the user in the list) to a global variable which will be always overridden with the last id of the corresponding row where you pressed the delete button.

and then you can just call the modal like this:

```
 $('#myModal3').modal('show');
```

After this you can get the id from the global variable and pass it to the ajax post

Comment: thx for the answer. I found another solution, but i guess yours will work too